# Solving for a constant multiplier of a variable

Tags: equation-solving

I would like to make this manipulation:

```
Solve[r Sin[α[t]] + l Cos[ϕ[t]] Sin[γ[t]] == 0, l*Cos[ϕ[t]]]
```

But it seems that the `Solve` function works only with variables.

However,

```
Solve[r Sin[α[t]] + l Cos[ϕ[t]] Sin[γ[t]] == 0, Cos[ϕ[t]]]
```

works

Have you an idea to have a direct way to code the first code line?

Comment: @Kuba i correct it

Comment: `Solve[r Sin[\[Alpha][t]] + l Cos[\[Phi][t]] Sin[\[Gamma][t]] == 0 /. 
    l Cos[\[Phi][t]] -> z, z][[1]] /. z -> l Cos[\[Phi][t]]`

Comment: somewhat related: http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/2078/5478

Answer (score 1):

I have a simple mind, so I tried the obvious.

```
sol =
 Map[
   Times[l, #] &,
   Solve[r Sin[α[t]] + l Cos[ϕ[t]] Sin[γ[t]] == 0, 
    Cos[ϕ[t]]],
   {3}][[1, 1]]
```

> `l Cos[ϕ[t]] -> -r Csc[γ[t]] Sin[α[t]]`

Check

```
r Sin[α[t]] + l Cos[ϕ[t]] Sin[γ[t]] /. sol
```

> `0`